# Use the squeeze theorem to prove the convergence of a set

Tags: real-analysis

Use the squeeze theorem to show that if $r>1$  then $(1 + r^n)^{1/n}$ converges.

If someone could also tell me how to do exponent and other math formatting, that'd be great. Sorry it's poorly written.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We have 
$$r^n\lt 1+r^n \lt r^n+r^n=2r^n.$$
Taking $n$-th roots, we get
$$r\lt (1+r^n)^{1/n}\lt 2^{1/n}r.$$

You probably know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{1/n}=1$.